# Twilio - Clicking a link will initiate an outbound call

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-php

i'm currently doing an automated interview using twilio and laravel. What would I like to achieve is something similar to this scenario:

- User inputs phone number on the web
- Twilio will send a sms with a link (link will expire within an hour or more)
- Clicking the link will initiate an outbound call to the user
- Automated interview will start.

Is this doable in Twilio? This is my first time using it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is doable!

Some links to help get you started:

- [Get a phone number from an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)
- [Send an outbound SMS with PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php)
- [Make an expiring link](https://www.temporary-url.com/)
- [Click to call with PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-php) (related to getting a phone number from an HTML form)

There are, of course, other tutorials and ways of doing this, but these links are a good starting place.

Good luck! :D